# How to hide the image element before login in AngularDart

Tags: dart, angular-dart, dart-html, dart-webui

I wanted to hide the image element at the left of SIGN IN button in the image, it's an image display before login. How can I do it in AngularDart?
[image]

app_component.html

```
    <div header class="custom-header">
        <img class="icon" [src]="fbService.user?.photoURL">
        <div id="user-name">{{fbService.user?.displayName}}</div>
        <div id="email">{{fbService.user?.email}}</div>
     </div>
```

app_component.css

```
.icon {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    margin-right: 16px;
}
```

Comment: Could you make this work?

Comment: No, I am using FirebaseService, and didn't find any example or documents to write dart code for "fbService.isLoggedIn"

Comment: I see. If I find time I'll have a look.

Answer (score 2):

```
<img *ngIf="authService.isLoggedIn" class="icon" [src]="fbService.user?.photoURL">
```

or

```
<img *ngIf="authService.isLoggedIn | stream" class="icon" [src]="fbService.user?.photoURL">
```

if `isLoggedIn` is a stream.

You would need a global service that provides the `isLoggedIn` status and is injected to the component that contains the `<img ...>` element (under the name `authService`.